# How to find Broadcast IP address from local IP address?

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming, ip-address

I am using Python 2.7 on Linux. I need to get local IP address (here it is 172.16.x.x). I can get IP address and it's corresponding netmask address but I'm not able to get broadcast IP address for the same IP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get IP Mask from IP Address and Mask Length in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508560/get-ip-mask-from-ip-address-and-mask-length-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the IP and the Subnetmask, you could simply calculate the Broadcastadress, by binary ORing the IP adress and the inverted subnetmask.

BC = ipadress || inv(subnetmask)

Comment: Thanks @Thargor for your help. But find the solution by using ipaddr.IPNetwork(vm).broadcast,got the answer from another post of stack overflow, where vm = ipaddress + "/" +netmask. Thanks both of you for the help