# Get my local IP address and subnet mask of the network via Python

Tags: python, networking

I want to get my local **IP address** and also the **subnet mask of the network** with a python code.
I tried this code for getting the IP address:

```
import socket
print socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

But I got this IP > 169.254.236.99, which is not my local IP address.

So maybe you can help me to do it? Thanks.

**Edit**: I found nice solution for the **IP address** that works on both Linux and Windows

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
```

So if you can help me with the subnet mask it will be pretty helpful :)

Comment: the problem is your Computer has multiple network adaptors and multiple addresses. the 169 is on a virtual interface to use for pcap.  You can use something like `ifaddr` from pip to list all of them.

Comment: You are right, i found the solution. Maybe you can help me with the subnet mask?

Comment: Do you still need an IP mask ? Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508732/9808870 However, you must know the number of bits for the mask (usually it is  unsigned 32bit integers).

Comment: This is not what I need because I don't know the number of bits of the mask.. but thanks for your comment

Comment: I'm sorry, I've modified my comment. The mask for IPv4 is typically 32bit (4 bytes x 8 bit).

Comment: Yes but I have only my local IP address, I can not get from it the subnet mask.

Comment: Another one option would also be to grab the data from `ipconfig` command - using the another module and method `subprocess.Popen()` or `os.system()`. With the help of the regex - python module `re`. But it takes a little more processor time. So only in the case if he used it irregularly and less often, it could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loopback is Not generally but always 127.0.0.1
You Local IP (LAN) is 192.168.1.11 (wifi)

Have a look at this: [Netifaces](https://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces)

That's a little thingy that will probably help you further. :-)

Comment: I have edited my question, if you can take a look it will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: For Linux, this should do the trick:

iface = "eth0"
socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM), 
                             35099, struct.pack('256s', iface))[20:24])

Comment: And what about Windows?

Comment: Hmmm...
I suggest you'll have a look at this: Netifaces
https://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/

Comment: Not generally. *Always, without fail* 127.0.0.1 is a *reserved* address for testing the network adaptor.

Comment: I found the solution there (Netifaces). I'll edit soon my question and I'll put there the code. Thanks!!!